# Can I use the same CSV file for multiples Thread groups?

Tags: jmeter

could find a precise answer to my question.

I have multiple Threads groups on my Test Plan, in all of them I created a CSV file to read a list of cars, for example:

Thread group 1   cars_thread_1.csv
Thread group 2   cars_thread_2.csv
Thread group 3   cars_thread_3.csv

But the list of cars didn't change inside the CSV files.

What's the recommended approach? Keep it like that or I can create a single CSV cars.csv and all of the threads read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, just place it at the same level as Thread Groups so all of them would be in the CSV Data Set Config's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

[image]

By default each thread will read next line from the file on each iteration, if this behaviour is not something you're looking for - you can amend [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) setting of the CSV Data Set Config.